# How would I calculate the number of experience required for the member's next level?

Tags: php, math, formula

I found a formula from another question here that calculates a member's experience level based on the total of exp they have.  What I need to do next is find out the number of exp required for the member's next level.  Basically, if a member is level 5, how much total experience would the member need to get to level 6?

```
$experience = 18714;

$level = pow(($experience / 1000), (7/10));  

echo floor($level); // This would output "7"
```

Update

```
<?php

$experience = 18714;

$level = floor(pow(($experience / 1000), (7/10)));

echo 'Current Level: '.$level.'<br>';

$experience = pow($level, 10/7) * 1000;

echo 'Next Level: '.($level + 1).' ( '.$experience.' required )';

?>
```

The above code will actually output the following

```
Current Level: 7
Next Level: 8 ( 16116.952067582 required )
```

I believe this is incorrect as far as my initial question is concerned... although it does find the exp required for the member's current level.  If the member is level 7 and has 18714 exp, it doesn't make much sense that level 8 requires less exp than level 7.

Comment: Well, the experience you are printing out is level 7 experience. You need to put `pow($level + 1, 10/7) * 1000;`

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense.. lol.  Thanks!  Not sure which answer to accept here since they're basically both the same lol.

Comment: You can pick any answer you want. I don't mind. Haha

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 I think you first need to define exactly which number is required to be the next level, having a pre-set variable type of thing. Can you elaborate as to what is required for each level?

Comment: I guess I'll accept the one that was posted first lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the formula:

[image]

[image]

Therefore

```
function getExpLevel($level) {
    return pow($level, 10/7) * 1000;
}
```

To calculate experience from level 5 to level 6. You can calculate as the following.

```
echo getExpLevel(6) - getExpLevel(5);
```

To calculate reminding experience to get to next level

```
echo getExpLevel($level + 1) - $experience;
```

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect changes that I made based on your suggestion.